# Where should I ask questions related to some interesting things about programming, but not about programming itself

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

We have all seen the most common function name "foo" in all C, C++ textbooks.

If I want to ask the question, "Where did the practice of using foo for function names originate from?", which StackExchange site should I use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797488/what-are-the-origins-of-foo-bar-and-baz  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795444/what-do-the-placeholders-foo-bar-and-baz-mean  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234507/to-foo-bar-or-not-to-foo-bar-that-is-the-question  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424580/when-foo-and-bar-is-not-enough  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868904/what-is-the-origin-of-foo-and-bar 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061234/what-does-foo-stands-for  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609/what-does-foo-really-mean  


etc etc etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the sort of question that would be a reasonable fit for [programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Mind you, you will also find that it is already answered there…

Comment: As you said: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/69788/what-is-the-history-of-the-use-of-foo-and-bar-in-source-code-examples

Comment: @Bart Updated language to reflect that it does exist; thanks for the link